# why does bash tell me that the command if is not found when I run the following code?

Tags: bash, if-statement, environment-variables

sorry, I am relatively new to bash, but

```
if [ ! -d /home/$USER/testfoo ]; then mkdir /home/$USER/testfoo; fi
```

has the desired effect of making a directory testfoo if it does not exist

but

```
TESTCMD="if [ ! -d /home/$USER/testfoo ]; then mkdir /home/$USER/testfoo; fi"
$TESTCMD
```

returns

```
if: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a variable as a command like this, it interprets the contents of the variable as the name of the command, not as a command followed by its arguments.

So if you you do `VAR="foo bar"` and then `$VAR` it looks for an executable (or built-in) called `foo bar`, not for an executable called `foo` that it calls with the argument `bar`.

To do what you want, you need to define a function:

```
TESTCMD() {
  if [ ! -d /home/$USER/testfoo ]
  then
    mkdir /home/$USER/testfoo
  fi
}
TESTCMD
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but TESTCMD() returns a carat and no new directory.... it appears that I dont need the parens

Comment: @David: Right, no parens. My bad.

Comment: can you explain why ssh user@server TESTCMD returns 'TESTCMD: no such file or directory'? or should this be another question?

Comment: @David: Because `ssh` tries to execute `TESTCMD` on the remote host where it's not defined.

Comment: ... thanks... so the answer to my problem is to run $ ssh user@server "if [ ! -d /home/$USER/testfoo ];   then     mkdir /home/$USER/testfoo;   fi;" its just that I have been using this format locally with CMD="qsub ..." with no problems.